# Why is this causing a stack overflow error? Directed graph

Tags: java, recursion, methods, directed-graph

I am trying to make a method that traverses a directed graph and all the vertexes are either grey or black, if it goes to black it marks a root as black and so signifies that it doesn't produce a tree. This one keeps giving me a stack overflow error. I would like it to even if it encounters a black one still continue the depth search just so that it doesn't miss any after that.

```
void colorRoots(Vertex root, Vertex v) {

    if (v.getColor() == DiGraph.BLACK) {
        root.setColor(DiGraph.BLACK);
    }

    for (Vertex g : v.neighbors()) {
        if (g.getColor() == DiGraph.GREY || g.getColor() == DiGraph.BLACK) {
            colorRoots(root, g); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method i use to traverse every root once and coloring. So i call this first before calling the above with roots.

```
void dfs(Vertex v) {

    if(v.getColor()==DiGraph.GREY) {
        v.setColor(DiGraph.BLACK);
    }else {
        v.setColor(DiGraph.GRAY);
    }


    for (Vertex g : v.neighbors()) {
        if(g.getColor()==DiGraph.WHITE || g.getColor()==DiGraph.GREY) {
        dfs(g); 
        }
    }   
    }
```

Could the issue be in the dsf method?

The whole plan i had in my head was traversing the graph once from all potential roots, then doing it again and marking all roots that can't produce a tree as black.

Comment: Hint: what happens if your graph contains a cycle?

Comment: I already have marked every vertex that is a part of a cycle as black.

Comment: Possible the issue is your `neighbors()` method. If `A --> B` and `B --> A`, then this would cause a stack overflow as its infinitely recursive.

Comment: @Masteprh33r really? check again.

Comment: The thing is that all vertexes that have been visited more than once are already black. I just need a way to break out of a cycle.

Comment: @Strikegently Yeah im not sure how to fix that

Comment: But your condition goes doen the recursion if they are BLACK.

Comment: if i have directed graph  `A --> B` ,`C-->D`, `C--->B`, `D--->C` , it doesn't seem to color A as black since this graph doesn't contain any trees.

Answer (score 1):

Check how you spelled "GRAY" vs "GREY" in dfs, might be the problem.

Comment: The spelling doesn't change grey and gray are the same, but yeah almost missed that, thanks.

Comment: If the color is Black, then it goes back to grey again in dfs. Check your if condition. Shouldn't it be: else if ( v.getColor() !=DiGraph.BLACK) ?

Comment: After changing the if method to else if it still produces the same result.

Comment: `if(v.getColor()==DiGraph.GREY) {
        v.setColor(DiGraph.BLACK);
    }else {
        v.setColor(DiGraph.GRAY);
    }` to `if(v.getColor()==DiGraph.GREY) {
        v.setColor(DiGraph.BLACK);
    }else if ( v.getColor() !=DiGraph.BLACK) {
        v.setColor(DiGraph.GRAY);
    }` ?  (Struggling with edit sorry, new here)

Comment: @Masteprh33r Check `colorRoots(root, g);` , pretty sure you need to pass v instead of root. You are always passing the same root.

Comment: Yeah its supposed the pass the same root untill the dsf ends and then i am calling a another one with a different root.

Comment: Then I think Lai in other response is on the good track. You could stack your visited vertex in a local HashMap (for O(1) access to check if node has already been visited). Someone could probably find a faster improvement however. I'm out after that, sorry if this didnt help and good luck with the rest!

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call at `dfs(g)` loop does not seem to have a logical end. Every processed Vertex object calls `neighbors()` and each neighbor `Vertex` calls neighbors and each neighbor called calls neighbors ...and on and on.

Comment: That seems to be the issue. I am not sure how i would change it to account for all different kind of directed graphs.

Comment: put a conditional statement that would definitely make it exit the call (e.g, if(condition) // then do call dfs(g))

Answer (score 0):

by changing DSF to

```
void dfs(Vertex v) {

        v.setColor(DiGraph.GREY);

    for (Vertex g : v.neighbors()) {
        if(g.getColor()==DiGraph.WHITE) {
        dfs(g); 
        }
    }   
    v.setColor(DiGraph.BLACK);
    }
```

Seemed to solve the issue.